# Python - get TLD

Tags: python, tld

I have a problem in function which should remove tld from domain. If domain has some subdomain it works correctly. For example:

Input: `asdf.xyz.example.com`

Output: `asdf.xyz.example`

Problem is when the domain has not any subdomain, there is dot in front of domain

Input: `example.com`

Output: `.example`

This is my code:

```
 res = get_tld(domain, as_object=True, fail_silently=True, fix_protocol=True)
 domain = '.'.join([res.subdomain, res.domain])
```

Function `get_tld` is from [tld library](https://pypi.org/project/tld/)

Could someone help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is `get_tld` implementation?

Comment: Sorry, I have forgotten to mention it. I am using tld library https://pypi.org/project/tld/

Answer (score 0):

With a very simple string manipulation, is this what you are looking for?

```
d1 = 'asdf.xyz.example.com'
output = '.'.join(d1.split('.')[:-1])
# output = 'asdf.xyz.example'

d2 = 'example.com'
output = '.'.join(d2.split('.')[:-1])
# output = 'example'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filtering. It looks like `get_tld` works as intended but `join` is incorrect

```
domain = '.'.join(filter(lambda x: len(x), [res.subdomain, res.domain]))
```

Answer (score 0):

another simple version is this:

```
def remove_tld(url):
    *base, tld = url.split(".")
    return ".".join(base)


url = "asdf.xyz.example.com"
print(remove_tld(url))    # asdf.xyz.example

url = "example.com"
print(remove_tld(url))    # example
```

`*base, tld = url.split(".")` puts the TLD in `tld` and everything else in `base`. then you just `join` tĥat with `".".join(base)`.